# How to select complete file in vi, to be pasted in gedit?

Tags: vim, gui, vi, clipboard

I know that doing `%y a` will yank complete file into register `a`. However this doesn't help in pasting the file content in another text editor (say gedit). What alternative is there for doing so?

Comment: Did you compile VIM with `X` support?

Comment: @warl0ck I didn't do anything special apart from apt-get install.

Comment: Read in the file from `gedit`? At least that's what I'd do the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if `vi` is required for this operation.

There is `xclip` utility that allows you to copy anything from console output to x server clipboard.

You should specify `DISPLAY=:0.0` environment and execute it like this:

```
cat file | xclip
```

or for remote file

```
ssh remote "cat file" | xclip
```

Or from `vi` (note, that this way will temporaly clear vi buffer content, to revoke it press `Esc` + `u`, data will stay in X cilpboard):

```
:%!xclip
```

Now you're able to paste it anywhere with middle mouse button (note, that `CTRL+V` or `shift+ins` won't work).

Comment: `:%!xclip` didn't work. It just deleted all the text in the file in `vi`.

Comment: @user13107 actually it works (all data are in clipboard), unfortunately all text is deleted. I'll put it the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a command line alternative to middle mouse button?

Comment: @user13107 use `xclip -o` for that.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than yanking into the `a` register yank into the `*` or `+` register to 
yank the file contents into the X clipboard using one of:

```
:%y*
:%y+
```

This does require that you're using a copy of vim that has X support compiled 
in and is able to connect to your X server. Which of those works better for you 
will depend on which type of clipboard the target editor uses.

You can even have one of those registers used as the default for yank and paste 
operations by including one of the following in your `.vimrc` file:

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

Comment: I get the following error message when using your solution: `E488: Trailing characters `

Answer (score 1):

If you're regularly finding yourself needing to use both Vim and gedit together, you should probably switch to gVim, the GUI version of Vim.

It seems you're using Ubuntu where gVim isn't installed by default. Use this command to get it:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

There's also `vim-gtk` which doesn't depend on Gnome, but since you're using gedit, you must be using one of the Gnome-based versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try,

`behave mswin`,

And use `^C / ^V` to copy and paste contents, not sure if this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by adding the following alias to my `.bashrc`

```
alias vim='gvim -v'
```

and in `.vimrc` set the clipboard to `unnamedplus`

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

Then yank:ed text is copied to the global buffer, and can be pasted in gedit with ctrl+v. Globally copied text can also be pasted using the vim `p` command

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode, `ggvG$` will select all text and save it in the `"*` register,
then go to gedit and click middle mouse, the text will be there.